# MS SQL If Selected is NULL Run another statement

Tags: sql-server

I have two sql statements,

```
select * from UserTable where role='HOD'

select * from UserTable where role='Supervisor'
```

I want the results to be in a way such that if the first statement returns nothing, I want the second statement to run and if first statement returns something, second statement do not need to run. Is there a way to do it, be it in a stored procedure or a SQLQuery?

Comment: Running *two* queries is more expensive that running only one that returns both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing two queries is more expensive than executing a *single* one that returns both result sets. It would be cheaper to filter the results on the client.

Even if you return all results in a single query, you *can* differentiate the two cases. For example, `HOD` always comes before `Supervisor`. You could use a ranking function like `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign a value to each row, depending on whether it matches `HOD` or `Supervisor`:

```
with a as (
    select * ,row_number() over (partition by Role  order by Role) as rn
    from UserTable 
    where Role in ('HOD','Supervisor')
)
select * 
from a
where rn=1
```

Another option is to combine a query that returns `HOD` with a query that returns `Supervisor` if `HOD` doesn't exist:

```
select * 
from UserTable 
where Role ='HOD'
UNION ALL 
select * 
from UserTable 
where Role ='Supervisor' 
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                      from UserTable 
                      where Role ='Supervisor')
```

The performance of both queries can be improved if `Role` is part of an index. The first query becomes equivalent to a simple index seek if the table has an index that covers all the returned fields. If the query returns only eg, ID, UserName, Role :

```
with a as (
    select * ,row_number() over (partition by Role  order by Role) as rn
    from UserTable 
    where Role in ('HOD','Supervisor')
)
select ID,UserName, Role
from a
where rn=1
```

and the table has a covering index:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_UserTable_Roles ON UserTable (Role,ID,UserName)
```

The resulting execution plan is a single INDEX SEEK on the index

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM UserTable WHERE ROLE = 'HOD'
        )
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM UserTable     WHERE ROLE = 'HOD'
END
ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM UserTable     WHERE ROLE = 'Supervisor'
END
```

Comment: This will execute the same query twice, costing as much as querying for *both* roles at the same time. Using `SELECT 1` does *not* make the query that much faster - the server *still* has to search for matching rows.

Answer (score 0):

This should do :

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FRom UserTable where role='HOD')
Begin
    select * from UserTable where role='HOD'
END
ELSE BEGIN
 select * from UserTable where role='Supervisor'
END
```

Comment: This will execute the same query twice.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : True, but that's how OP wants it. Its one of the possible solution. :)

Comment: No, there is no reason to run *two* queries. The OP wants different *results*, not two different queries

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Transact SQL then a good page to read about this is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql

In the Transact SQL instance, the general version of what you are looking for is;

```
IF Boolean_expression   
     { sql_statement | statement_block }   
[ ELSE   
     { sql_statement | statement_block } ]
```

Comment: First, running two queries is a bad idea. Second, where would that boolean expression come from?